# How to disable dropdown autocomplete in text input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

I've created a text input using the code in the link above. How can I stop this dropdown of recent searches from appearing when clicking/typing on the input?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `autocomplete="off"` to your input tag:

`<input autocomplete="off">`